# How to set class members values to another class

Tags: java

I have two classes one is vo class for DB layer and another one is Bean class for view layer. But two classes are have the same members, in order to save the values in db I set all the field values from Bean class to VO class. Then I pass the VO class to hibernate or procedure.

Example 
vo.setId(bean.getId());
etc..

Is it any other way to set the values from Bean to VO and VO to Bean? Like( vo=bean || bean=vo )

Comment: is there any validation ? i mean can  we use third party library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you apache BeanUtils:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

Here you have the following method:

org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.copyProperties();

As you stated your vos and beans have the same attributes. This method will copy the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If these are different objects there isn't. You can create constructor which does what you need:

```
public SomeClass1(SomeClass2 other) {
    this.id = other.getId();
    ....
}
```